# Scikit-learn estimator not changing predictions when random_state variable changes

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am trying to compute prediction intervals for a classifier I trained in scikit-learn. Even after setting a new `random_state` parameter in my pipeline, this does not seem to change my results when refitting on the data.  What can I do about this?  This is a relevant snippet of the code I am using:

```
SEED_VALUE = 3

t_clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('lgbm', LGBMClassifier(class_weight="balanced",random_state=SEED_VALUE, max_depth=20, min_child_samples=20, num_leaves=31))

                 ])
states = [0,1,2,3]

///

for state in states:

    train_temp = train.copy()
    t_clf.set_params(lgbm__random_state=state)
    t_clf.fit(train_temp, train_temp['label'])
    t_clf.predict_proba(test)   

# output from predict probability doesn't change with varying states
```

The same occurs when trying to change shuffle order.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when shuffling I did not set the `replace` parameter to `True` which prevented randomness from being inserted into the process.

```
SEED_VALUE = 3

t_clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('lgbm', LGBMClassifier(class_weight="balanced",random_state=SEED_VALUE, max_depth=20, min_child_samples=20, num_leaves=31))

                 ])
states = [0,1,2,3]

///

for state in states:

    train_temp = train.copy().sample(frac=1, replace=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    t_clf.fit(train_temp, train_temp['label'])
    t_clf.predict_proba(test)   

# output from predict probability should be different each run
```